# asp:HyperLink build NavigateUrl within Repeater using XPATH data

Tags: asp.net, repeater, xmldatasource

I am using a repeater for some products I am listing.

I'm trying to build an asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl using both hardcoded text as well as XPATH data.

NavigateUrl='mypage.aspx?ID=<%#XPath("THEID")%>&name=<%#XPath("THENAME")%>'

Obviously this isn't working.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<asp:HyperLink 
    runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("mypage.aspx?ID={0}&name={1}", XPath("THEID"), XPath("THENAME")) %>' 
    Text="some link" 
/>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks.  Would you be willing to also show how I would add the content of a Textbox into that string as well?

Comment: You can't do this in server side language as the content might be changed by the user. You will need to use javascript for this.